# Rotating UIView and still seeing the old position of the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios

I am rotating a view using `src.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);`, it is working well but I am still seeing the old position of the view (like that: http://cl.ly/233y403c2C1C451r1f28).

How can I refresh the view ? The view is in a UITableViewCell, I tried to refresh the row of the cell or even the tableview but it doesn't work.

Here is my drawRect method :

```
  if (nil != _image) {
    [_image drawInRect:rect contentMode:self.contentMode];
  } else {
    [_defaultImage drawInRect:rect contentMode:self.contentMode];
  }
```

The view that I am rotating is embedded in a UIImageView which is part of the cell.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Could you post your drawRect method? And say how the view is organised in the cell, i.e. are you subclassing UITableViewCell or presenting a view which can be rotated as the contentView or something else?

Comment: @Adam Eberbach - I just edited my post and added what you wanted! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If figured it out. I was trying to rotate the image while I was downloading it. When I rotate it from a delegate callback that is call when the image is loaded everything works fine.
All of that makes perfect sense !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have two copies of your image view there. When you rotate the top one, the bottom one is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the background colour of the UIView you're overriding drawRect in? Before drawRect is called, the background colour is applied to the context. Ensure you have a background colour set (i.e. not set to `[UIColor clearColor]`, for example).

Also, what's the `opaque` property of your UIView set to?